# Can't seem to pass function to setTimeout argument array in node.js (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, settimeout

This works:

```
function test(msg:string){
   console.log(msg);
}

setTimeout(test, 1000, ["Hi!"];
```

...in that it will print out "Hi!" to the console after one second.

This also works:

```
function test(){
   console.log("Hi!");
}

function callTest(next: () => void){
   next();
}

callTest(test);
```

In that it also prints out "Hi!" to the console.

The following results in the error "TypeError: next is not a function".  Why?

```
function test(){
   console.log("Hi!");
}

function callTest(next: () => void){
   next();
}

setTimeout(callTest, 1000, [test]);
```

It sure looks like a function to me!  If the 1st code snippet works it shows that I have the form generally right to use setTimeout and send parameters to the callback, and the 2nd code snippet shows that this is the correct form to call a function passed in as a parameter - why isn't my use of setTimeout in the 3rd code snippet working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to pass the list of arguments directly at the end of the arguments you pass to `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(callTest, 1000, test);
```

If you had more arguments, you'd do:

```
setTimeout(callTest, 1000, test, a, b, c);
```

There's no need to put them in an array like you'd do if you were to call [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). The reason you are getting an error is that the way you do it `setTimeout` passes an array of length one that contains a reference to the `test` function.

The reason your earlier example with the string works is that `console.log` is absolutely okay with dumping an array to the console. And there's no opportunity for TypeScript to make an issue of it because this is the [definition of `setTimeout`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.1.5/lib/lib.d.ts#L17858) when there's a list of arguments to pass to the function that will be called:

```
declare function setTimeout(handler: any, timeout?: any, ...args: any[]): number;
```

As you can see type checking is turned off by the use of `any`.

Comment: Ah - so you don't pass an array of parameters, you just keep listing them?  Like if callTest took 2 params it would be like: `setTimeout(callTest, 1000, param1, param2)`?  Why didn't I get a TypeError in my first example where I was passing an array as the parameter where it was expecting a string?  (You are totally correct and I'll mark this as the correct answer, but I just want to totally understand it.)

Comment: The `setTimeout` you show in your comment is correct. Your first example had an error. In the `callTest` function you were calling `test()` directly rather than calling `next()`.

Comment: That was just a posting error - I fixed it in the question.  Your answer did it for me (just waiting for the time to pass to mark as complete).  I was curious why in the first code snippet it didn't give a type error, but I guess console.log is OK with taking in an array of a single string and the function signature wouldn't have thrown a TypeError so that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, I focused on the wrong example. I've edited my answer to address the earlier example. Let me know if the explanation needs clarification.

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  I'll just say that I made this error from reading the documentation which says `setTimeout(callback, delay[, ...args])`, but I read it as `setTimeout(callback, delay,[ ...args])`.  One character difference (my error) and it sent me down this rabbit hole!